# Top-Down Car in JBox2D libGDX movement issues

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, game-physics, jbox2d

I am trying to implement a Java version of *the top down car* game based on [Emanuele Feronato's "Two ways to make Box2D cars"](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/04/06/two-ways-to-make-box2d-cars). I know some basics of [box2d](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/box2d/info) and for the most part I converted the code to Java as is with few exceptions.

However, when I run the program my car does not move whatsoever.

If I make the everything a dynamic body all of the wheels (Except for the Left Front) start to move back and forward flinging the car back and forward but in the end getting no where. The front two joints are revolute joints with motor's on each while the back are prismatic, so correct me if I'm wrong but the front two should be the only ones "rotating"/moving. I feel like I'm doing something horribly wrong but everywhere I look its always in action script so I'm not 100% sure whats wrong.

I've checked and all of the wheels are in the right positions and the joints are put to the correct wheels as well. I've checked the motor speed and it is also running. My x component of the "ldirection" and the "rdirection" are always 0, so it is killing the lateral velocity, while the y is  always a value. So really it should be moving forward right?

**The Left Front wheel always stays the same distance from the body as the body shifts up and down. So the Left Front seems to be working properly. I checked all of my code to make sure the right front wheel was made the same as the left wheel.**

Starting car
[image: Starting Car]

When accelerating forward only the two right wheels and back left wheel move back and forth.
[image: When accelerating forward only the Two right wheels and back left wheel move back and forth.]
[image]

When I begin to turn the two front wheels the back two wheels still stay in line with the car but start moving in a somewhat diagonal fashion. Eventually when the front wheels are turned around 90 degrees they start to almost rotate the centre of the joint.
[image: When I begin to turn the two front wheels the back two wheels still stay in line with the car but start moving in a somewhat diagonal fashion]
[image]
[image]

Initialization

```
  this.world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), false);
    this.box2Drender = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    this.LeftPJointDef = new PrismaticJointDef();
    this.RightPJointDef = new PrismaticJointDef();
    this.RightJointDef = new RevoluteJointDef();
    this.LeftJointDef = new RevoluteJointDef();

    this.CarBody = new PolygonShape();
    this.RightRWheelShape = new PolygonShape();
    this.RightFWheelShape = new PolygonShape();
    this.LeftRWheelShape = new PolygonShape();
    this.LeftFWheelShape = new PolygonShape();

    this.LeftRWheelDef = new BodyDef();
    this.RightRWheelDef = new BodyDef();
    this.RightFWheelDef = new BodyDef();
    this.LeftFWheelDef = new BodyDef();

    this.bodyD = new BodyDef();
    this.CarFixDef = new FixtureDef();

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.Cpos = new Vector2(x,y);

    this.RRW = new Vector2((this.x + (this.x * XPrc)), (this.y + (this.y * -YPrc)));
    this.RLW = new Vector2((this.x + (this.x * -XPrc)), (this.y + (this.y * -YPrc)));
    this.FRW = new Vector2((this.x + (this.x * XPrc)), (this.y + (this.y * YPrc)));
    this.FLW = new Vector2((this.x + (this.x * -XPrc)), (this.y + (this.y * YPrc)));

    this.WheelSizeX = this.width * 0.25f;
    this.WheelSizeY = this.length * 0.30f;
    //setting bodyDef damping
    bodyD.linearDamping = 0.5f;
    bodyD.angularDamping = 0.5f;

    //Adding bodyDef to the world and setting type as Dynamic
    body = world.createBody(bodyD);
    body.setType(BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody);

    //setting the body position in the world using the Vector given.
    body.setTransform(this.Cpos, (float) ((Math.PI) / 2));

    //Adding the calculated Position vecotrs of the wheel's to each wheel def.
    RightFWheelDef.position.add(FRW);
    LeftFWheelDef.position.add(FLW);
    RightRWheelDef.position.add(RRW);
    LeftRWheelDef.position.add(RLW);

    //Adding the wheels to the world using the Wheel Defs.
    RightFWheel = world.createBody(RightFWheelDef);
    LeftFWheel = world.createBody(LeftFWheelDef);
    RightRWheel = world.createBody(RightRWheelDef);
    LeftRWheel = world.createBody(LeftRWheelDef);

    RightFWheel.setType(BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody);
    RightRWheel.setType(BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody);
    LeftFWheel.setType(BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody);
    LeftRWheel.setType(BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody);

    //Setting the car(box) and wheel size
    CarBody.setAsBox(this.length, this.width);
    LeftFWheelShape.setAsBox(WheelSizeX, WheelSizeY);
    LeftRWheelShape.setAsBox(WheelSizeX, WheelSizeY);
    RightRWheelShape.setAsBox(WheelSizeX, WheelSizeY);
    RightFWheelShape.setAsBox(WheelSizeX, WheelSizeY);

    CarFixDef.shape = CarBody;

    RightFWheel.createFixture(RightFWheelShape, 1);
    RightRWheel.createFixture(RightRWheelShape, 1);
    LeftFWheel.createFixture(LeftFWheelShape, 1);
    LeftRWheel.createFixture(LeftRWheelShape, 1);

    body.createFixture(CarFixDef);

    LeftJointDef.enableMotor = true;
    RightJointDef.enableMotor = true;

    LeftJointDef.maxMotorTorque = 500;
    RightJointDef.maxMotorTorque = 500;

    //Setting Front Wheel joints in respects to the wheels and body
    LeftJointDef.initialize(body, LeftFWheel, LeftFWheel.getWorldCenter());
    RightJointDef.initialize(body, RightFWheel, RightFWheel.getWorldCenter());



    this.LeftJoint = (RevoluteJoint) world.createJoint(LeftJointDef);
    this.RightJoint = (RevoluteJoint) world.createJoint(RightJointDef);

    LeftPJointDef.enableLimit = true;
    RightPJointDef.enableLimit = true;
    //Translation Limit
    LeftPJointDef.lowerTranslation = 0;
    LeftPJointDef.upperTranslation = 0;
    RightPJointDef.lowerTranslation = 0;
    RightPJointDef.upperTranslation = 0;

    //Setting Rear wheel joints in respects to wheel and body
    LeftPJointDef.initialize(body, LeftRWheel, LeftRWheel.getWorldCenter(), new Vector2(1, 0));
    RightPJointDef.initialize(body, RightRWheel, RightRWheel.getWorldCenter(), new Vector2(1, 0));



    //adding the P Joints to the world.
    this.LeftPJoint = (PrismaticJoint) world.createJoint(LeftPJointDef);
    this.RightPJoint = (PrismaticJoint) world.createJoint(RightPJointDef);
```

Here is my update method.

```
    KillOrthoVelocity(LeftFWheel);
    KillOrthoVelocity(RightFWheel);
    KillOrthoVelocity(LeftRWheel);
    KillOrthoVelocity(RightRWheel);

    //Driving
    float r1 = LeftFWheel.getTransform().getRotation();
    Vector2 ldirection = new Vector2((float) -Math.sin(r1), (float) Math.cos(r1));
    ldirection.scl(enginespeed);
    float r2 = RightFWheel.getTransform().getRotation();
    Vector2 rdirection = new Vector2((float) -Math.sin(r2), (float) Math.cos(r2));
    rdirection.scl(enginespeed);

    LeftFWheel.applyForce(ldirection, LeftFWheel.getPosition(), true);
    RightFWheel.applyForce(rdirection, RightFWheel.getPosition(), true);


    //Steering
    float movespeed;

    movespeed = steerAng - LeftJoint.getJointAngle();
    LeftJoint.setMotorSpeed(movespeed * AngleSpeed);

    movespeed = steerAng - RightJoint.getJointAngle();
    RightJoint.setMotorSpeed(movespeed * AngleSpeed);

    world.step(dt, 6, 2);
```

With KillOrthoVelocity being similar to getting the "ldirection"

```
    Vector2 localP = new Vector2(0, 0);
    Vector2 velocity = body.getLinearVelocityFromLocalPoint(localP);

    float r = body.getTransform().getRotation();
    Vector2 sideways = new Vector2((float) -Math.sin(r), (float) Math.cos(r));
    sideways.scl(velocity.dot(sideways));

    body.setLinearVelocity(sideways);
```

Any advice would be very appreciated! Even just a clue would be extremly helpful!
Thanks!

Comment: That's probably too much code for anyone to wade through and vizualize what's happening. How about screenshot/video or something. btw why would a top-down car have a prismatic joint in it?

Comment: To my knowledge of box2D (Which isn't too much) prismatic joints are joints that stay in a given direction to the desired body and only slide, that is why I continued to use prismatic joints for the rear two wheels. I set the upper and lower translation to 0 so they shouldn't be able to slide vertically and thus should just stay parallel to the body. @iforce2d

Comment: I suspect that you need to inject a little object oriented design into this problem. You should have an object called "Wheel" that has properties that you can set that would cause it to behave like a left front, or right front wheel, or like rear wheels. Have your wheels and car body extend or aggregate box2d objects.

Not using an object oriented approach would get complicated and confusing pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code 


RaceCar::RaceCar( b2World* world )  
{       
b2Vec2 race_car_pos( 13.0f,
        13.0f );

/ Create race car chassis 
{       
    // Physics Body Shape           
b2Vec2 verticies[8];            
verticies[0].Set(  1.5f, 0.0f  );   
        verticies[1].Set(  3.0f, 2.5f  );   
        verticies[2].Set(  2.8f, 5.5f  );   
        verticies[3].Set(  1.0f, 10.0f ); 
            verticies[4].Set( -1.0f,
        10.0f );        
    verticies[5].Set( -2.8f, 5.5f  );   
        verticies[6].Set( -3.0f, 2.5f  );   
        verticies[7].Set( -1.5f, 0.0f  );

b2PolygonShape body_shape;      
    body_shape.Set( verticies, 8 );

// Physics body definition  
        b2BodyDef body_def;     
        body_def.type
        = b2_dynamicBody; 
//          body_def.position =b2Vec2(3,3);     
        // Physics Body Fixture             
b2FixtureDef body_fixture;      
    body_fixture.shape = &body_shape;           
body_fixture.density = 0.1f;

m_chassisPhysicsBody = world->CreateBody( &body_def );  
        m_chassisPhysicsBody->CreateFixture( &body_fixture );           m_chassisPhysicsBody->SetUserData( this );

m_chassisPhysicsBody->SetTransform( race_car_pos, 0.0f ); 
        }

// Tires 
{           b2Vec2 pos = m_chassisPhysicsBody->GetPosition();

// Top left tire    
        {
                        RCTire* tire_top_left = new RCTire( world );
                        tire_top_left->setPosition( race_car_pos );
                        m_tires.push_back( tire_top_left );

                        b2RevoluteJointDef joint_def;
                        joint_def.enableLimit = true;
                        joint_def.lowerAngle = 0.0f;
                        joint_def.upperAngle = 0.0f;
                        joint_def.bodyA = m_chassisPhysicsBody;
                        joint_def.localAnchorB.SetZero();
                        joint_def.bodyB = tire_top_left->getPhysicsBody();
                        joint_def.localAnchorA.Set( -3.0f, 8.5f );
                        b2RevoluteJoint* joint = static_cast<b2RevoluteJoint*>( world->CreateJoint( &joint_def ) );
                        tire_top_left->setJointToChassis( joint );          }

// Top right tire   
{
                        RCTire* tire_top_right = new RCTire( world );
                        tire_top_right->setPosition( race_car_pos );
                        m_tires.push_back( tire_top_right );

                        b2RevoluteJointDef joint_def;
                        joint_def.enableLimit = true;
                        joint_def.lowerAngle = 0.0f;
                        joint_def.upperAngle = 0.0f;
                        joint_def.bodyA = m_chassisPhysicsBody;
                        joint_def.localAnchorB.SetZero();
                        joint_def.bodyB = tire_top_right->getPhysicsBody();
                        joint_def.localAnchorA.Set( 3.0f, 8.5f );
                        b2RevoluteJoint* joint = static_cast<b2RevoluteJoint*>( world->CreateJoint( &joint_def ) );
                        tire_top_right->setJointToChassis( joint );             }

// Bottom left tire 
{
                        RCTire* tire_bottom_left = new RCTire( world );
                        tire_bottom_left->setPosition( race_car_pos );
                        m_tires.push_back( tire_bottom_left );

                        b2RevoluteJointDef joint_def;
                        joint_def.enableLimit = true;
                        joint_def.lowerAngle = 0.0f;
                        joint_def.upperAngle = 0.0f;
                        joint_def.bodyA = m_chassisPhysicsBody;
                        joint_def.localAnchorB.SetZero();
                        joint_def.bodyB = tire_bottom_left->getPhysicsBody();
                        joint_def.localAnchorA.Set( -3.0f, 0.5f );

                        b2RevoluteJoint* joint = static_cast<b2RevoluteJoint*>( world->CreateJoint( &joint_def ) );
                        tire_bottom_left->setJointToChassis( joint );           }

                    // Bottom right tire            {
                        RCTire* tire_bottom_right = new RCTire( world );
                        tire_bottom_right->setPosition( race_car_pos );
                        m_tires.push_back( tire_bottom_right );

                        b2RevoluteJointDef joint_def;
                        joint_def.enableLimit = true;
                        joint_def.lowerAngle = 0.0f;
                        joint_def.upperAngle = 0.0f;
                        joint_def.bodyA = m_chassisPhysicsBody;
                        joint_def.localAnchorB.SetZero();
                        joint_def.bodyB = tire_bottom_right->getPhysicsBody();
                        joint_def.localAnchorA.Set( 3.0f, 0.5f );
                        world->CreateJoint( &joint_def );
                        b2RevoluteJoint* joint = static_cast<b2RevoluteJoint*>( world->CreateJoint( &joint_def ) );
                        tire_bottom_right->setJointToChassis( joint );          }       }   }
```